# apache superset : unexpected error: supersetapierror: fatal error

Tags: apache-superset

My Apache Superset installation has been running for at least 6 months without any changes.

Suddenly I get this error today, when I open a dashboard

"unexpected error: supersetapierror: fatal error"

I can login but can't view any dasboards or charts

When I open a chart I get this error:

{"errors": [{"message": "string argument without an encoding", "error_type": "GENERIC_BACKEND_ERROR", "level": "error", "extra": {"issue_codes": [{"code": 1011, "message": "Issue 1011 - Superset encountered an unexpected error."}]}}]}

I'm running Apache Superset 1.3.2 and Python 3.7.2 in an virtual environment

How to solve this issue?

I can't figure out what to do.

Do I need to make an update of Superset?